# Any way for a framework to force linkage of a class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, storyboard, xib

I am making a framework that has a class that extends UIView for use in iOS apps.  If I just use storyboard to put the view on a screen, then this isn't enough to force the linker to include my class in the app, and so I get

```
Unknown class MyClassName in Interface Builder file.
```

In the app, there are several ways I could force the linkage, but I want to know if there's something I could do in my .framework that would force apps to link to specific classes.

I tried a trick that I would do in C, but it isn't legal Objective-C.  In the .h for my view, I tried to create a static Class global variable, like so

> static Class myClassInit = [MyClass class];

That way when the app includes my .h, this code would put the usage in their compilation unit, hopefully forcing a link.  Unfortunately, this doesn't compile because statics need to be known at compile time -- I get this:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Any other ideas for what I can do to the framework project to force the app to link to my class by just using it in storyboard and including the .h?

For example, there are other questions with answers to add linker flags to the app or have the app call `[MyClass class]`.  I would like a solution that doesn't force the app maker to do anything beyond normal usage of the class.

For example, is there a pre-processor directive or other Objective-C way to force the linkage?

And just in case you didn't know this: Having an outlet or even setting properties of the view is not enough to get it linked.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out something that works

If you put this at the bottom of a header, after the `@end`, it will force linkage

```
#define UNIQUENAME(s) s##__COUNTER__
Class UNIQUENAME(MyClassForceLink)()
{
    return [MyClass class];
}
```

You cannot use a static function (the linker removes it), and if you include the header more than once in your app, you need unique names so that there is no conflict of multiply defined symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards and XIBs are "not code", but rather serialized object graphs. They aren't considered/seen by the linker. Likewise, if the header is just present in the project (to inform IB) but never `#import/#included` into a compiled source file, the linker will similarly be totally unaware of it.  You will need to `#import/#include` the header in a file that is actually seen by the compiler and linker. (You may even have to make a "real" reference to something, I'm not 100% sure about the linker semantics here.)

You can pass your library to the linker as part of "Other Linker Flags", but I'm not sure how editing a build setting is any easier than "`#import`ing the header into at least one compiled file."

Comment: #importing the header doesn't work.  You have to make a real reference to something like alloc or class, using properties isn't enough.  I would prefer not to do this -- this is a framework meant to be used by others.  I'd like them to just need to include the header and do what they would normally do.  I don't want them to have to do anything special in their build (other than include the framework)

Comment: Looks like you found a way.

Comment: Hi, I get this problem, when i connect my label from storyboard to the controller. where exactly should I put this? in my controller.h file?